# Hibernate on dynamic partitioning of database tables

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

We have a transaction table where daily insertions are around 1 million transaction. We have done the partitioning on the basis of insertion date.

This has resolved our issue in insertion time. However, we are still facing below issues:
1. Hibernate Criteria select still scans all the partitions.
2. We are creating partitioned tables daily manually, so while table creation, all the inserts are getting blocked and table is getting locked and we are facing slowness.

The entity table mapping is over the parent table.

Is there a way, we initiate all database operations like select, insert, updates over partitioned tables only without locking the tables and how the entity table should look like.

Note: We are using postgresql database.

Comment: Why not simply create partitions for e.g. the complete year in advance?

Comment: In that case we need to create 365 partitions and it will take some time to create. We cannot have downtime in the application. That's why we create one table at a time where we face only small amount of delay.

Comment: Creating the partitions in advance does not need any downtime

Comment: Application is already running currently.

Comment: So what? You can create new partitions without affecting inserts into existing ones.

Comment: That is the main problem. While creating new partitions and applying rules, the parent table is getting locked.